# Можно ли сказать, что глаголы изменяются по родам?

Tags: грамматика, род

**Для существительного** (в качестве сравнения):

**Категория рода внутренне присуща имени существительному.** Род не возникает в существительном как результат его синтаксической связи с другими словами (например, **род имени прилагательного, глагола** зависит от того существительного, с которым они связаны)...  Имя существительное может иметь только один род, и это родовое значение остается в нем неизменным. **Существительные имеют род, а не изменяются по родам.** **https://www.kazedu.kz/referat/154432/2

**Для глагола:** Род – **синтагматически** определённая словоизменительная категория, которая в ед. числе обозначает **отнесённость действия к лицу мужского или женского пола, или координацию с родом предметного существительного.** https://studfiles.net/preview/6131401/page:25/

Но это определение подходит для высшей школы, а в школе обычной можно ли  говорить, что глагол и прилагательное имеют значение рода или нужно говорить, что они не имеют значение рода, а только изменяются по родам.

И вопрос: **Получается, что существительные имеют род как постоянный признак, а глаголы и прилагательные только изменяются по родам, но значение рода не имеют?** Или это неверно?

Сам термин "изменяется по родам" обозначает наличие **грамматических форм** (или соответствующих окончаний) **для выражения грамматического значения.** Даже существительные в форме мн. числа или несклоняемые существительные не имеют формы для выражения рода, хотя род является их постоянным признаком.

То есть можно иметь грамматическое значение, но не иметь формы для его выражения. А можно, наоборот, не иметь постоянного грамматического значения, но иметь грамматическую форму  с целью согласования с другими частями речи.

**Примечание.** В конце XX века в системе развивающего обучения был известен **учебник Репкина для младшей школы,** где малым деткам очень доходчиво объясняли **разницу между грамматическим значением и грамматической формой.** И вот мне кажется, что современные школьники и в старших классах ( а также взрослые пользователи языка) не всегда различают эти понятия. Но, может быть, я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 3):

По Розенталю, *категории рода и числа являются нехарактерными для грамматической структуры глагола. Лишь отдельные формы глагола обладают категорией рода.*
(Валгина Н.С. Розенталь Д.Э. Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык, Москва: Логос, 2002)

Если исходить из этой концепции, можно сказать, что ***глагол*** в отдельных своих формах (прошедшее время, сосл. наклонения и причастия ед. числа) **изменяется** (в смысле выбора формы в пределах категории **рода**) для согласования с родом существительного, связанного с выражаемым действием. Лишь в таком условном смысле можно говорить об "изменении глаголов по родам".

Comment: Интересное дело, а я думала, что формы глагола не обладают категорией рода, а выражают категорию рода.  Категория рода  - непостоянный признак  глагола, он приобретает значение рода, когда его отдельные формы согласуются с существительными  (местоимениями) в  роде.  А как надо говорить про глагол, если он изменяется по родам только условно? А прилагательное изменяется по родам? Можно ли вообще употреблять этот термин, например: существительное изменяется по падежам и числам. А если можно, то почему я не могу сказать то же самое про глагол: глаголы изменяются по родам в  прошедшем времени?

Comment: @Jasmin, в АГ-80 тоже говорится, что глагол в прошедшем времени изменяется по родам.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию,  а то я стала думать, что это упрощенный вариант для школьного уровня.